# NSDate has the opposite AM/PM value

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I am using this code to convert the `NSDate` to my local timezone, the correct hour and day is shown but the AM/PM part is always incorrect.

```
let date1 = "2015-05-14 19:00:00 +0000"
let date2 = "2015-06-12 04:50:00 +0000"
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzzz"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date1)

let timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

let seconds: NSInteger = timeZone.secondsFromGMTForDate(date!)
var d = NSDate(timeInterval: NSTimeInterval(seconds), sinceDate: date!)
```

`date1` comes back as `May 14, 2015, 7:AM`

`date2` comes back as `Jun 11, 2015, 4:50PM`

Both of these should have opposite AM/PM values, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is your local timezone? It works here (GMT+1).

Comment: Mountain time, hmm thats very strange.

Comment: So you would expect May 14, 12:00 noon and June 11, 21:50 ?

Comment: NSDate does not have a time zone, so what are you actually trying to achieve? date1/date2 are *strings* specifying a time in GMT. If you want to print `date` in your local time zone then use a date formatter to convert it to a string. – If your intention is to *interpret* date1/date2 as if they were in your local time zone then your correction goes into the wrong direction (replace `seconds` by `-seconds`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(From my above comment)* `NSDate` does not have a time zone. date1/date2 are *strings* specifying a time in GMT. If you want to print `date` in your local time zone then use a date formatter to convert it to a string.

If your intention is to *interpret* date1/date2 as if they were in your local time zone instead of GMT then your correction goes into the wrong direction (replace `seconds` by `-seconds`).

Your results are not
with opposite AM/PM values but simply 12 hours earlier than you expected
them to be (which makes sense because Mountain time is GMT-06).